# vba scrape by sub division and class

Tags: vba, excel

form this html scrap, I just want to get "NO IPLAN PRODUCT - 1" this is only last time under columno4,

`<div  class="row02">
        <div class="column01">
            <span class="outputLabel">Originator:</span>
            <span class="outputText" id="originator_sessionheader">DORIS M MORRIS - SUBSCRIBER/RECIPIENT</span>
        </div>
        <div class="column02">
            <span class="outputLabel">Tax ID:</span><span class="outputText"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="column03">
            <span class="outputLabel" style="vertical-align: 2px;">PBB
                <!--  IE11 remediation changes -->
                <img class='imgLink' onclick="openKMWindow('https://svckm.uhc.com/eAgent/iq/ISET/gateway.jsp?create=kb%3AUHG&report()=p[prem_based_ben]');return false;" src="/chap/images/qm_drkBlue.gif" width="13" height="13" alt="PBB KM" title="PBB KM"/>
            </span>
            <span class="outputText" style="vertical-align: 2px;">:N</span>
        </div>
        <div class="column04">
            <span class="outputLabel style="vertical-align: 2px;">iPlan
            <!--  IE11 remediation changes -->
                <img class='imgLink' onclick="openKMWindow('https://svckm.uhc.com/eAgent/iq/ISET/gateway.jsp?create=kb%3AUHG&view()=c[i_iplan_ind]');return false;" src="/chap/images/qm_drkBlue.gif" width="13" height="13" alt="IPLAN KM" title="IPLAN KM"/>
            </span>
        <span class="outputText" style="vertical-align: 2px;cursor:pointer" title="NO IPLAN PRODUCT">:1</span>`

I tried multiple vba codes but not getting any solution,

Comment: Show what you've tried....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're asking but to get the value 1 from the NO IPLAN tag bit you could use this rudimentary text string manipulation that I've recently started to employ as a function due to XML parsing problems:

```
Sub ho()

Dim str As String
Dim schSTR As String
Dim t1 As Integer
Dim t2 As Integer
Dim t3 As Integer

str = *this is where your HTML scrape would be assigned*
schSTR = "NO IPLAN PRODUCT"">:"

If InStr(1, str, schSTR, vbBinaryCompare) Then
  t1 = InStr(1, str, schSTR, vbBinaryCompare) + Len(schSTR)
  t2 = InStr(t1, str, "<", vbBinaryCompare)
  t3 = t2 - t1
  result = Mid(str, t1, t3)
  MsgBox result
End If
End Sub
```

This will give you a message of "1."

If I've understood your requeset properly this will work for any html page/scrape that contains the schSTR variable (in this case "NO IPLAN PRODUCT">:"